# In C# Object Initializer Syntax Why we cant assign one property to another in it

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Hi I was using C# Object Initializer like

```
public class Invoice
    {
        public decimal GrossSum { get; set; }
        public decimal GrossSumComp { get; set; }
    }
    public class ABC()
    {
        public Invoice Invoice {get;set;}

        public ABC(decimal grossSum)
        {
            Invoice=new Invoice()
            {
                GrossSum=grossSum,
                GrossSumComp=**GrossSum**
            };
        }
    }
```

And I saw we can't assign value of One Property to another in it , Like above I tried to assign GrossSum to GrossSumComp and there I got Compilation error. Just curious to know Why It dont allow this. Any help will be highly apericaited.

Comment: Because you are in a different class. You have no instance of Invoice even if you have access. You could set the property if it would be static. I assume that you're mixing a nested with an inherited class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's how it's specified. `GrossSum` in the second line is a reference to a variable named `GrossSum` not a property of the object being initialized.

To paraphrase Eric Lippert. For a feature to be implemented it has do be

- Proposed
- Analysed
- Designed
- Implemented
- Tested

Those all incur a cost, so they should add value to match the cost and preferably exceed the cost.

If there's a simple work around to the feature, odds are that the cost is likely to be (a lot) higher than the potential value.

In your case you can simply assign `grossSum` instead of `GrossSum`. That's a simple work around

Answer (score 1):

The error message in that case is your answer:

```
The name 'GrossSum' does not exist in the current context
```

How would the compiler know what `GrossSum` is without a given context? There's no way to specify `this` or something similar to indicate that the `GrossSum` property you're referring to is the one defined on the object you're in the process of initializing.

Comment: The specifications could have had a rule similar to how it's determined that a local is used and not a parameter (or instance field) with the same name. So the specifications _could_ have been written in a way that made it legal and unambiguous. That's not the case but it's not because the compiler couldn't possibly know that GrossSum reference to a property og the object being initialized. It could know but the specifications says it shouldn't